# Is TLS necessary for port 25 for MX delivery?

Tags: postfix, starttls

I am in the process of implementing a new Postfix implementation on an existing environment which is extremely old. While doing so I am requiring all clients to connect securely on either 465 or 587 for relay access.

The existing postfix environment that I inherited has the following setting:

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

According to Postfix documentation, which cites RFC 2487:

> A publicly-referenced SMTP server MUST NOT require use of the STARTTLS
>   extension in order to deliver mail locally. This rule prevents the
>   STARTTLS extension from damaging the interoperability of the
>   Internet's SMTP infrastructure. A publicly-referenced SMTP server is
>   an SMTP server which runs on port 25 of an Internet host listed in the
>   MX record (or A record if an MX record is not present) for the domain
>   name on the right hand side of an Internet mail address.

Given that I want outbound SMTP relay access to be exclusively performed on 465/587, my question is simply this:

**Is there any circumstance that TLS is used for local mail delivery for an MX host?** (I have the required overrides in master.cf to enable ssl/tls, startls).

I can't find a definitive answer if other MTA's establish secure connections to MX hosts in order to deliver locally.

My goal is to prevent any relay access (Authenticated or otherwise) on port 25, however I do not want to disable tls security on 25 if it will interfere with local delivery from the internet.

Thanks in advance.

main.cf

```
#
# Postscreen
#

#postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -1 # Pending Postfix 2.11

postscreen_access_list          = permit_mynetworks, cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen/access.cidr
postscreen_greet_banner         = $myhostname [POSTSCREEN] ESMTP
postscreen_blacklist_action     = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_action         = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold      = 3
postscreen_greet_action         = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map      = pcre:$config_directory/postscreen/dnsbl_reply_map.pcre
postscreen_dnsbl_sites          = zen.spamhaus.org*3
        b.barracudacentral.org*2
        bl.spameatingmonkey.net*2
        bl.spamcop.net
        dnsbl.sorbs.net
        psbl.surriel.com
        bl.mailspike.net
        #swl.spamhaus.org*-4
postscreen_whitelist_interfaces = static:all
postscreen_bare_newline_action  = enforce
postscreen_bare_newline_enable  = no
postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
postscreen_pipelining_enable    = no

#
# Server
#

myhostname                      = relay1.sanitized.fqdn
mydomain                        = sanitized.fqdn
myorigin                        = $myhostname
mynetworks                      = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/24
mydestination                   = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
sendmail_path                   = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
relay_domains                   =
local_recipient_maps            =
inet_interfaces                 = localhost, 192.168.0.12
inet_protocols                  = ipv4
strict_rfc821_envelopes         = yes
disable_vrfy_command            = yes
local_recipient_maps            =

#
# SMTPD
#

append_dot_mydomain             = no
biff                            = no
relayhost                       =
smtpd_banner                    = $myhostname ESMTP
#smtpd_client_restrictions      = sleep 5
smtpd_delay_reject              = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions       = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_error_sleep_time          = 30
smtpd_soft_error_limit          = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit          = 20
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtp_helo_timeout               = 5
#smtp_connect_timeout           = 5
smtp_host_lookup                = native


#
# SMTP-AUTH configuration
#
smtp_sasl_auth_enable           = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps         = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/mailboxes.cf
smtpd_sasl_local_domain         = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_type                 = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path                 = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks  = $mynetworks
broken_sasl_auth_clients        = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
#smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter     = plain, login

#
# TLS configuration
#

smtpd_tls_security_level        = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file             = /etc/pki/tls/certs/godaddy.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file              = /etc/pki/tls/private/godaddy.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile                = /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
smtpd_tls_loglevel              = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header       = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 10800s
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache
tls_random_source               = dev:/dev/urandom
tls_random_exchange_name        = /var/lib/postfix/prng_exch
smtpd_tls_auth_only             = yes

#
# Virtual configuration
#

virtual_alias_domains           =
virtual_mailbox_base            = /
virtual_mailbox_domains         = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps            = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/mailboxes.cf
virtual_alias_maps              = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/autoreply.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/aliases.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/groups.cf
virtual_minimum_uid             = 110532
virtual_uid_maps                = static:110532
virtual_gid_maps                = static:101
proxy_read_maps                 = $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $smtp_sasl_password_maps
```

master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1      smtpd 
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  #-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  #-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_sender_login_maps=proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_login_maps.cf
  #-o smtpd_sender_sasl_password_maps=proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_login_maps.cf
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
policy    unix  -   n   n   -   0   spawn user=nobody
  argv=/bin/python /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Answer (score 0):

`may` is the safe and preferred option, I would be more inclined to suggest signed certificates. If both endpoints support TLS, it will be used.

Many email providers run **opportunistic TLS** (Gmail even added visual indicators to email sent without tls).

Comment: I have signed certificates in place, however I have not found out how to leave "may" in place and at the same time disallow authentication/relay on 25. I do have smtpd_tls_auth_only set to "yes", but ultimately I would like to completely segregate outbound and inbound traffic on their respective ports.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, post your configs. These settings aren't related.

Comment: Are there specific sections you would like to see? postconf -v is extremely lengthy and I'd hate to have anyone have to sift through that mess to get to pertinent config

Answer (score 0):

Your config description doesn't make sense.  If you want mail to flow you need port 25 open.  You cannot presume that all mail will come in via 587 or with TLS.  Relaying however, shouldn't be possible from the outside and there are several setting that allow you to only allow relaying from inside and optionally require tls.

Comment: Port 25 will be open. I do not want users using 25 to send mail via their mail clients, rather 465/587. Port 25 I want only for the internet to deliver mail to local mailboxes